# Your Ruby version is 2.1.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I just upgrade my [Rails project](https://github.com/acandael/beautysalonapp2) to use Ruby 2.2.1 on my local machine.

When I deploy my Rails application to the production Ubuntu 14.04 server with Capistrano, I get this error message:

```
bundle stdout: Your Ruby version is 2.1.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1
```

I upgraded my Ruby version on the server with Rbenv:

```
rbenv install 2.2.1
rbenv global 2.2.1
rbenv rehash
```

Then I tried to deploy my Rails app again, but I'm still getting the error:

```
bundle stdout: Your Ruby version is 2.1.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1
```

I guess I'm missing something here.

Comment: make sure you don't have .ruby-version file in your project.

Comment: you mean my Gemfile on the server? I updated my local Gemfile to use ruby 2.2.1

Comment: just found out that I forgot to update the Ruby version in my Capfile. But now I get another error when I do 'cap production deploy': ERROR rbenv: 2.2.1 is not installed or not found in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1

Comment: try to set 2.2.1p85 in capfile.

Comment: Hi Anand, adding a patch number to the ruby version this solve the issue, I'm still getting the error message when I try to do 'cap production deploy': ERROR rbenv: 2.2.1 is not installed or not found in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a line to [deploy.rb](https://github.com/acandael/beautysalonapp2/blob/master/config/deploy.rb):

```
set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
```

or:

```
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.1p85'
```

or move the Ruby verison from Gemfile to .ruby-version and add this to deploy.rb:

```
set :rbenv_ruby, File.read('.ruby-version').strip
```

Comment: Hi Vetal4eg, thanks I add set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.1' to config/deploy.rb, but when I do 'cap production deploy' I get the error message: ERROR rbenv: 2.2.1 is not installed or not found in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1

Comment: @Toontje so install it :)

Comment: Hi Andrey I did install it. When I run ruby -v on my local machine, I get ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin13]

Comment: I also installed it on the server, when I run ruby -v on the server I get: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @Toontje try :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.1p85' in deploy.rb or set :rbenv_type, :user

Comment: adding the patchnumber p85 didn't fix the issue, still getting error message when I try to 'cap production deploy': ERROR rbenv: 2.2.1 is not installed or not found in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1

Comment: how about set :rbenv_type, :user ? (-: